# Solr Re-indexing taking time

Tags: indexing, solr

We have indexed data with 143 million rows(docs) into solr.It takes around 3 hours to index.I usde csvUpdateHandler and indexes the csv file by remote streaming. 
Now ,while i re-index the same csv data,it is still taking 3+ hours.

Ideally,since there are no changes in _id values,it should have finished quickly Is there any way to speed up re-indexing?

Please help with this.

Comment: Are we really talking about .. 143 documents? Only 143?

Comment: oh it was a typo,it was 143 million rows..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably almost as efficient as you can be when it comes to actual submission of data - a possible change is to only submit the data that you know has changed due to some external factor.

Solr would have to query the index for each value anyway, then determine which fields has changed before reindexing, which would probably be more expensive that it already is.

For that number of documents, 3 hours is quite good. You should work on reducing the number of rows submitted instead, so that the total amount of work is less than what it used to be. If the CSV is sorted and rows are only appended, keep the last _id available and only submit the CSV rows present after the id before submitting the CSV to Solr.

Comment: Thanks for the info..:-)